# Open third party extension with TYPO3 extension builder

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

There is a custom TYPO3 extension in our installation which was obviously bootstrapped using the TYPO3 extension builder. But I cant access it using the "load" button.

Where do I tell the extension builder that he is in charge of this extension?

The original developer of the extension is no longer available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ExtensionBuilder search for an `ExtensionBuilder.json` file in the extension directory. Here are all settings for the extension and models defined. Without this file the ExtensionBuilder doesn't know how the extension was created and which domain models and their fields exist or are defined. So you can't edit an Extension without this file in the ExtensionBuilder

Comment: Thanks. That's it. Lets hope I'll find this file somewhere. Reconstructing it from the source seems to be a lot of work :/

Comment: Maybe you can do the changes in the files instead of using the ExtensionBuilder. The ExtensionBuilder can overrides changes that are made manualy.

Comment: I'd like to extend the existing set of models within this extension by one new entity. I'm not that into T3 development so the extension builder is the only way I can handle the huge amount of boilerplate ^^

Comment: You have to modify three files for that: The model class (at `Classes/Domain/Model`, the [TCA](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/6.2/) file (at `Configuration\TCA`) and the `ext_tables.sql` in the extension root dir. You will find several tutorials about this, or many qeustions to the special field here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is wrong! Accepted answer is right!**

Whether an extension shows up in the load dropdown in Extension Builder depends on the presence of the file `Configuration/ExtensionBuilder/settings.yml` in your extension.

If it‘s not there (which seems to be the case) you could look for a dedicated branch - some people create such branch at the beginning and delete Extension Builder stuff in their main branch.

Comment: As I know this file is only for overwrite rules of files like classes and templates.

Comment: Yes this file contains class builder and overwrite settings.

Comment: @RenéPflamm yes of course, you were right - I looked in the wrong method. Your answer is correct. I‘ll edit my answer to make that clear.